# git: How to redo a merge conflict resolution (before committing the merge)?

Tags: git, merge

I did a

```
git merge FETCH_HEAD
```

and, after git told me that there is a conflict in one file, I did a

```
git mergetool
```

which in my case runs SourceGear DiffMerge as a GUI mergetool. Immediately after saving the merged file, I realized that I made a bad mistake. I just want to forget the merge and do it all over.

Since I didn't have executed a "git add" yet, let alone committed anything, I thought I could erase my mistake and redo the merge easily like this:

```
git reset FILENAME
git merge FETCH_HEAD
git mergetool
```

This does not work. "git merge" by this time tells me

```
fatal: You have not concluded your merge (MERGE_HEAD exists).
Please, commit your changes before you can merge.
```

But of course I don't want to commit the screwed-up merge. "git mergetool" complains

```
No files need merging
```

I guess I made a mistake at the "git reset" command. What is the proper way to do this?

ADDING:

I did

```
git merge --abort
```

then again:

```
git merge FETCH_HEAD
```

This yielded

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge: ...

git status
```

says:

```
On branch ....
Your branch is up-to-date with ......
Changes not staged for commit:
    modified:   nVP.ini
Untracked files:
    nVP.ini.orig
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Just an idea: Would simply a git checkout of nVP.ini bring back the situation before the merge?

Comment: If `nVP.ini` is the conflict file you can just `git checkout HEAD -- nVP.ini`.  `git reset` just resets the index entry, you want the worktree clean too, so checkout the HEAD version.   During a merge you can also `git checkout --ours nVP.ini` for the same effect,

Answer (score 37, accepted):

To undo a bad conflict resolution before committing, `git checkout -m -- $thefile`.

```
$ git merge 3fac3
Auto-merging file.txt
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in file.txt
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
$ vi file.txt         # fix all the conflicts. do it wrong.
$ git add file.txt    # <--- ooops
$ git checkout -m -- file.txt    # <--- the correct un-oops-ifier here
```

and `file.txt` is back to the failed-automerge state.

Note that you can also specify the conflict-reporting style, so if you ordinarily do the default two-diff style but you've got a baffling one and want to see the original too, you can do

```
git checkout -m --conflict diff3 -- file.txt
```

Comment: This just results in `error: pathspec 'xxx' did not match any file(s) known to git.` error.

Comment: Krzaku you get that error if git can find the file, you will need to enter the path as git status shows it.

@jthill Thanks for this answer, you saved me about 4 hrs or merge hell.

Answer (score 3):

[jthill's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29608028/git-how-to-redo-a-merge-conflict-resolution-before-committing-the-merge/29609456#29609456) was exactly what I was looking for, but I thought I'd point out that if you are one of those who prefers `git restore` to `git checkout`, the equivalent commands are:

```
git restore --merge -- <filepath>
```

and

```
git restore --conflict=diff3 -- <filepath>
```

Answer (score 2):

i had the same issue,

a branch was merged in dev, which erased another branch changes during conflict resolution.

i've used cherry-pick for that :

```
git cherry-pick {merge commit sha of missing branch code} -m 1
```

i was able to redo the whole conflict resolution process.