# How to re-view merge conflicts

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, merge-conflict-resolution

I did `git pull origin <branch-name>` and got merge conflicts in multiple files.

My project is open in Microsoft's visual studio code. I viewed one of the files and chose the wrong "change". I clicked, "undo" but then it removed all the merge conflict markers. Unfortunately, my VSC editor is on autosave, so as soon as I clicked on a different file, it saved the previous file without the merge conflict markers.

I'd like to re-view those merge conflict markers. But when I try to `git pull...` again, it complained that I have unresolved merge conflicts. So I added all my files and committed the work - but now `git pull...` says I'm up to date.

**How can I view the merge conflicts again** (without using the web editor which git says my merge conflicts are too complex for)?

Comment: If you *have* committed the merge, you must repeat the merge.  If you *have not* committed the merge, see [git: How to redo a merge conflict resolution (before committing the merge)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29608028/1256452)

Comment: Incidentally, this is yet another reason I recommend *avoiding* `git pull`, at least until you're pretty good at the commands that `git pull` runs for you: if you know that `git pull` means *run `git fetch`, then run a second command, in this case `git merge`* you are ahead of someone who doesn't know that!

Answer (score 0):

The only way I was able to re-view merge conflicts was by resetting to my previous commit and then re-pulling:

```
git reset --hard [commit-sha]
git pull origin <branch-name>
```

Comment: Yup, that works.  Committing merge results leaves behind the now-useless conflict-detection data; to get it back, rerun the merge. Same data, same process, same results. Nothing wrong with that.  Also, there are many merge strategies and options for good reason, rerunning a merge with different options can save an awful lot of manual tedium.

Comment: If I have already resolved 50 files and then I realize that on file 51 I need to go back, taking the whole work back to start over from scratch won't hold water

Comment: Not saying there is an easy way for it, by the way.... but it's a fair question. There _should_ be a way to get the original conflict back from the grave.

Answer (score 0):

This is where the `d` in `dvcs` really gets its grip on: you can do anything you want in your local repo.  Git's a full-service history editor, and you made some edits you'd like to undo. So undo them:

```
git reset --hard @^
```

and rerun the merge

```
git merge origin/branch-name
```

and you're back to where you were before the oops.

Any conflict resolutions you want to retrieve from the previous merge, just retrieve them:

```
git checkout @{1} -- this.file that.file and.another
```

or this might be easier:

```
git checkout @{1} -- .
git checkout -m -- file.that.was.merged.wrong
```

Comment: If I have already resolved 50 files and then I realize that on file 51 I need to go back, taking the whole work back to start over from scratch won't hold water

Comment: Not saying there is an easy way for it, by the way.... but it's a fair question. There _should_ be a way to get the original conflict back from the grave.

Comment: It seemed to me you were asking specifically how to restore merge conflicts after committing, If you want to restore merge conflicts _before_ committing, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29608028/git-how-to-redo-a-merge-conflict-resolution-before-committing-the-merge/)

Comment: `git checkout -m` nice! Thanks!