# Recall a git three-way merge in mergetool after merge?

Tags: git, merge, mergetool

This is somewhat similar [git: How to redo a merge conflict resolution (before committing the merge)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29608028/git-how-to-redo-a-merge-conflict-resolution-before-committing-the-merge) - except, I do not really want to re-do a merge.

This is my problem: I've tried merging a branch, and I got:

```
Auto-merging myfile.c
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in myfile.c
```

Ok, fine, so I do the usual:

```
git mergetool -t meld myfile.c
```

Ok, so `meld` opens, I do my merge, all seems good ... except, I compile, and it crashes.

I can see the point where it crashes, so I just want to recall the same state in `meld`, that I had upon the last save in `meld`, before closing it (which causes `mergetool` to exit).

However, if I just repeat the command - it refuses to run:

```
$ git mergetool -t meld myfile.c
No files need merging
```

I have not yet committed, but as usual, after exit from mergetool, `myfile.c` has been added to the index.

Note that I do not want to undo and repeat the merge, because I have to go through like 30+ conflicts, which are all fine, and do not need a change - I just want to repeat the same state in `meld` for `myfile.c`, that I had upon the last save, before exiting `meld` and `mergetool`.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: This may not work well with meld, but it's an option in general for mergetool: (1) save the currently merged file somewhere (as an untracked file, in /tmp, whatever, out of reach of Git). (2) run `git checkout -m myfile.c` to re-create the conflicted state. (3) use your favorite method of merging, noting that you have the saved file to recover most of what you already did in that one file.

Comment: Possibly silly, but the easiest way I can think of is to copy your merged file aside, `git restore -m -- myfile.c`, run mergetool again, and paste the contents of the file into the merged pane

Comment: I don't use meld (nor even `git mergetool`) - I just edit the files directly, build, test, etc., until I am satisfied, and then run `git add` on the resolved file(s). This way I'm not at the mercy of the various tools...